# Inconsistent Whitespace handling in XQuery?

Tags: xml, xquery

I'm confused about how to get XQuery to handle whitespace like I want it to.
Say I have to following XML:

```
<body>
to<lb/>
<choice norm="Miss">Mi<glyph ref="#sm-long-s>s</glyph>s</choice>
<name type="person"><forename>Margaret</forename> <surname>Hamilton</surname></name><lb />
<name type="place">S<hi rend="superscript">t</hi> James's</name>
</body>
```

If I use this code

```
for $body in /body
return replace(string-join(
    for $t in $body//node()
    return
        typeswitch($t)
        case text() return
            if (
                sum(
                    for $a in $t/ancestor::*
                    return
                        typeswitch($a)
                        case element(choice) return 1
                        default return 0
                )=0
            ) then $t
            else null
        case element(lb) return ' '
        case element(choice) return $t/@norm
        default return null
),"\s+"," ")
```

I get the following output:

```
to MissMargaretHamilton St James's
```

rather than the expected

```
to Miss Margaret Hamilton St James's
```

Is there a way to fix that?

<sub>PS: There is no such thing as `<forename>` in the actual code, but I introduced it in this example to showcase both the linebreak and the space between > and < being ignored.</sub>

Comment: White space handling is implementation dependent, but can usually be configured. For example, BaseX has the [`CHOP` option](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Options#CHOP). What implementation are you using?

Comment: Have a look at http://wiki.tei-c.org/index.php/XML_Whitespace for a discussion.

Comment: @Jens, where in the spec does it say that white space handling is implementation dependent? I think the result of this query is entirely prescribed by the spec.

Comment: I will never dare arguing with you about specs, but doesn't your answer pretty much agree with my statement?

Comment: Yes, I realized afterwards. XQuery is 100% prescriptive about how whitespace in the XDM is handled, but it leaves some flexibility about how the XDM is constructed from source XML. There are two "standard" mappings of XML to XDM (depending on whether or not you use a schema), and it seems this example isn't using either of them: which is allowed by the standards, but not recommended. Saying that the whole thing is implementation dependent is a bit strong...

Comment: The problem disappeared when I opened the XML files with CHOP disabled. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some very strange things about this query. For example, it seems to me that this subexpression:

```
            sum(
                for $a in $t/ancestor::*
                return
                    typeswitch($a)
                    case element(choice) return 1
                    default return 0
            )=0
```

is just a convoluted way of writing `empty($t/ancestor::choice)`.

And what is "null"? It looks to me like an element name that won't match anything in your input, hence a convoluted way of writing `()`.

What's more, your XML isn't well-formed: there's a missing quote on the ref attribute. That makes me suspect that the problem as submitted is not the problem as originally executed, so you might have inadvertently removed the clue to the solution.

However, if I fix the missing quote and run the query in Saxon, it produces the expected output. So I think the problem is that there is a bug (or to be more polite, a non-conformance) in your XQuery processor.

LATER: On reflection, I suspect you are using an XML parser that strips whitespace text nodes. This is a notorious quirk of the Microsoft MSXML parser, and makes it pretty useless for handling mixed content where such whitespace is significant. I believe it can be configured to behave "properly", but I've completely forgotten how.

The XQuery specs do leave processors some latitude in this area: they allow the XDM input tree to be constructed in any way that the processor fancies, which might include stripping all whitespace, or stripping every occurrence of the letter "x". At this point it's a question of whether you find the design choices made by your particular XQuery processor acceptable.

Comment: I simplified the XML considerably and typed it by hand, so it's no wonder that the quote was missing.
It's nice to know that about `empty($t/ancestor::choice)` and `()`, though I'll probably continue to use `null` because its meaning seems more transparent than `()` to me.

Anyway, thanks for the hint about the parser stripping whitespace. Reminded me that BaseXgui has an option to chop or not chop whitespace when importing new files. Worked after dropping and re-adding the database with that option off.

Answer (score 1):

For good measure, here is how I would rewrite your query:

```
normalize-space(string-join(
    for $t in /body//node()
    return
        typeswitch($t)
        case text() return $t[not(ancestor::choice)]
        case element(lb) return ' '
        case element(choice) return $t/@norm
        default return ()
))
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplification.

Answer (score 0):

XML whitespace-handling can get quite tricky. I often have to experiment to get things just right.

I like to write transformation functions, and primarily handle different elements in my `typeswitch`:

```
declare function local:transform($x)
{
  typeswitch($x)
  case element(choice) return $x/@norm/fn:string()
  case element(name) return
    if ($x/forename)
    then fn:string-join($x/node()/fn:string(), " ")
    else $x/fn:string()
  case element() return
    for $y in $x/node()
    return local:transform($y)
  default return fn:string($x)
};

let $x := (: your sample xml :)
return fn:replace(fn:string-join(local:transform($x), " "), "\s+", " ")
```

This sample should return your desired output. And it's easy to add cases for other elements, comment out existing cases, etc.